# Select MySQL tables ending in _timestamp with matching regxp

Tags: mysql, regex, rlike

I'm trying to isolate some tables in a mysql database that match a pattern which can be described as

**some-name**_*10-digit timestamp*

eg:

```
| oxseohistory_1381393508       |
| oxseohistory_1382427650       |
| oxseohistory_1382617597       |
```

Is there a way to use a regular expression which matches everything with 10 digits at the end? Like this one?

```
\d{10}$
```

I tried

```
 SHOW TABLES FROM `usrdb_xxxx` WHERE `Tables_in_usrdb_xxxx` RLIKE '\d{10}$';
```

which did not work (empty set).

Comment: You should use `[[:digit:]]{10}$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MySQL does not support `\d`, you can use

```
[[:digit:]]{10}$
```

Or

```
[0-9]{10}$
```

Comment: Add the underscore?  `_[[:digit:]]{10}$`  This also limits the number to only 10 digits.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, if all these digits appear after an underscore, it can be added to restrict the context further.